# how can I use the extension methods in C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, metadata

I am writing a silverlight framework plugin and I want to find my metadata in global config metadata based on the metadata key. I'm using the following statement.

```
var metadata = smfPlayer.GlobalConfigMetadata.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Key == METADATA_ID);
```

I'm getting a compilation error saying:

Error   1   'Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Utilities.Metadata.MetadataCollection' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Utilities.Metadata.MetadataCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\cygwin\home\Weijia Li\test\testplayer\ConvivaMMPPFPlugin\ConvivaMMPPFPlugin.cs   45  63  ConvivaMMPPFPlugin

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you import the `System.Linq` namespace?

Comment: Yes, I imported "System.Ling".

Comment: It is not "System.Ling", but "System.Linq"

Comment: Ok, I see what the problem is. I did import "System.Linq", however, the reference "System.Xml.Linq" was not added to my project. Thanks everyone.